# getMethod() arguments to add components

Tags: java, reflection

I have created the required buttons,panels and the frame and now i want to add everything where it needs to,but i have to create the .add method using the       getMethod() but i dont now what arguments to use.Also do i have to create different methods for the buttons and the panels or is there something more general?

```
Class frame = Class.forName(frame_path);
Object obj = frame.newInstance();
Method meth = frame.getMethod("setVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
Method meth2 = frame.getMethod("setDefaultCloseOperation", Integer.TYPE);
meth.invoke(obj, true);
meth2.invoke(obj, EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Class jb1 = Class.forName(rec_button_path);
Object objJb1 = jb1.newInstance();
Class jb2 = Class.forName(round_button_path);
Object objJb2 = jb2.newInstance();
Class jb3 = Class.forName(rec_button_path);
Object objJb3 = jb3.newInstance();

Class jPanel1 = Class.forName(container_path);
Object objJP1 = jPanel1.newInstance();            
Class jPanel2 = Class.forName(container_path);
Object objJP2 = jPanel2.newInstance();

Method add1 = jPanel1.getMethod(".add", jb1);   // i need helpo here
```

Comment: Why are you programming like this... Class.forName??

Comment: i am reading from XML files thats why

Comment: @GiannisPerpirakis why do you think that means you have to do all this reflective awkwardness?  Even if you have to do the Class.forName shenanigans, you can cast the newInstance objects to the appropriate interface and call their methods normally.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html this is the api, how to invoke methods... I guess there are lot of questions on SO, I will search

Comment: I guess Tunaki found it before me, follow duplicated link

Comment: i am afraid its not helpful